# Socket.io не отсылаются данные со стороны клиента

Tags: javascript, flask, socket.io, socketio-client

Есть скрипт JS. В упрощенной версии выглядит так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket_msg = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/message');
    socket_msg.on('connect', function(data){
      socket_msg.emit("auth_client", "test");
    });
});
```

Не отсылаются данные. Подскажите в чём может быть причина?
Версия socket.io js - 3.1.1
Данные отсылаются на сервер Flask. На сервере установлен Flask-Socketio 5.1.0

Сервер:

```
from gevent import monkey

monkey.patch_all()
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import socket

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='gevent')

@socketio.on('auth_client', namespace='message')
def test_connect(data):
    print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        socketio.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, use_reloader=False, debug=True, log_output=True)
    except socket.error as socketerror:
        print("Error socketio: " + str(socketerror))
```

Comment: через вкладку нетворк в DevTools сообщение идет? И добавьте сервер

Comment: Вот что в DevTools в WebSocket Сообщениях:  `42/message,["auth_client", ["test"]]`

Comment: попробуйте на клиента просто написать io.connect('http://localhost:5000')

Comment: Нет, так вообще не хочет подключаться к серверу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была на самом деле в том, что я неправильно указал `namespace='message'`.
Нужно лишь изменить на:

```
namespace='/message'
```